# ArrayList<String> наполнять пока не остановят

Tags: java, arraylist

Наполняю список с клавиатуры пока не введу специальное слово, потом вывожу все слова на экран кроме последнего.

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
ArrayString<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i = 0; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++){//я же не знаю сколько раз я захочу водить слова:)
if(reader.readLIne().eqals("end")) break;//то самое условие с спец. словом
else list.add(reader.readLine());//а если не оно то продолжаем
}

for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
System.out.println(list.get(i));
 }
```

ломаю голову почему выводит в консоль каждое второе слово.
Добавляю вывод размера списка.

```
 System.out.println(list.size());
 System.out.println(list.get(i));
```

И знаете что? показывает, что размер списка ровно в половину меньше колличества введённых элементов. Т.е. он выводит все, вот только не все записывает в список. Кто знает почему?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все проще

```
    String stop = "end";
    List <String> inputList = new ArrayList <>();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(true) {
        String nextLine = sc.nextLine();
        if (stop.equals(nextLine)) break;
        else inputList.add(nextLine);
    }

    System.out.println(inputList);
```

P.S. А выводит через один элемент потому, что вы в коллекцию пишите через один, ведь в цикле дважды вызывается reader.readLine()

Comment: добавлю свои пять копеек, `while(true)` не очень хорошая практика, обычно делают так `while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())`

Comment: А вы уверены, что при такой постановке вопроса вас сможет понять автор вопроса?))

Comment: Если не поймет то пусть просто поверит на слово)